# Тень дочерних блоков пропадает

Tags: css

есть такой пример

Тень работает нормально. Только блок box1 в плотную к нижней границе родительского блока  Но только начинаю делать отступ у родительского блока  - тень пропадает.

```css
.box {
width: 100%;
height: 500px;
background: #e7e7e7;

}
h3 {
  text-align: center;
  top: 30%;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 30px;
}
.box1 {
  width: 30%;
  background: #fff;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  
}
.shadow {
  position: relative;
}
.shadow:before, .shadow:after {
  position: absolute;
  background: #777;
  width: 40%;
  max-width: 200px;
  content: '';
  top: 80%;
  left: 10px;
  z-index: -1;
  bottom: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 15px #000;
  transform: rotate(-4deg);
  
}
.shadow:after {
  right: 10px;
  left: auto;
  transform: rotate(4deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="box1 shadow"><h3>Привет мир </h3></div>
  <div class="box1 shadow"><h3>Привет мир </h3></div>
  <div class="box1 shadow"><h3>Привет мир </h3></div>
    
</div>
```

Comment: Сделал отступы - нечего не пропало. Покажите пример кода, при котором у вас пропала тень

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/romweb/cr6rdmfj/17/

Comment: Добавил box - height  - тень пропала

Comment: либо . box1 { margin-bottom: 20px; } тень пропала

Comment: при добавлении background - тень пропадает

Answer (score 1):

Суть в том, что у вас было несоответствие стилей. Т. е. у вас `before` и `after` скрывались за другими элементами (то за фоновым блоком, то за самим блоком). Нельзя ставить `z-index` в отрицательное число, так как элемент переместится за другие блоки у которых не указан `z-index` (т. е. уйдёт под все блоки).

```css
.box {
  width: 100%;
  background: #e7e7e7;
  height: 300px;
}
h3 {
  text-align: center;
  top: 30%;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 30px;
}
.box1 {
  width:30%;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
 }
.body {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
 }
.shadow {
  position: relative;
  /* z-index:-2; */

}
.shadow:before, .shadow:after {
    position: absolute;
    background: #777;
    width: 40%;
    max-width: 200px;
    top: 80%;
    content: '';
    left: 10px;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: -12px;
    box-shadow: 0 15px 15px #000;
    transform: rotate(-4deg);
}
.shadow:after {
  right: 10px;
  left: auto;
  transform: rotate(4deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="box1 shadow"><div class="body"><h3>Привет мир </h3></div></div>
  <div class="box1 shadow"><div class="body"><h3>Привет мир </h3></div></div>
  <div class="box1 shadow"><div class="body"><h3>Привет мир </h3></div></div>
</div>
<div class="test"></div>
```

<sub>[jsfiddle-cr6rdmfj-19](https://jsfiddle.net/cr6rdmfj/19/)</sub>

Comment: Зачем написать код в `jsfiddle` вместо того что бы добавить его в ответ здесь?

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan, добавил